# How to replace a .txt file Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to replace a text file that exists as IsolatedStorageFile with a text file from web.

```
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
IsolatedStorageFileStream rootFile = store.CreateFile("InTheRoot.txt");
IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile(rootFile, "http://example.com/test.txt" , true);
```

Whats the mistake here ? thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `File.Copy(rootFile, "http://example.com/test.txt" , true);` ? This code doesn't work? Any error or exception message?

Comment: You need to provide much more information

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile(string, string, bool)  -- I am getting this error

Comment: any other ideas guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile() to download a file from the internet.

The quick and dirty way is to use a hidden WebBrowser control:

XAML

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Navigated="Browser_Navigated" Visibility="Collapsed"></phone:WebBrowser>
<TextBlock x:Name="Text"></TextBlock>
```

C#

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://example.com/test.txt"));
    }

    private void Browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        var filename = "InTheRoot.txt";

        if (store.FileExists(filename)) store.DeleteFile(filename);

        using (var stream = store.CreateFile(filename))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                writer.Write(Browser.SaveToString());
            }
        }

        using (var file = store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                Text.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

The main problem with this is that it wraps the text file contents in <HTML><BODY> elements.

This is not really to be recommended but it will get you up and running.

The better way to retrieve content from the web is using BackgroundTransferRequest as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/08/15/creating-a-ui-for-background-transfer-requests.aspx)

Comment: same error :( >>>>> var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            store.CopyFile("http://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt ", "InTheRoot.txt", true);

Comment: I will check it soon, I am a bit busy nowadays. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
IsolatedStorageFile.CopyFile(rootFile, "http://example.com/test.txt" , true);
```

to this :

```
store.CopyFile("InTheRoot.txt", "http://example.com/test.txt" , true);
```

that will fix "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property*" error, and next error "*cannot convert from 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream' to 'string'*". Because expected type of the first parameter is `string` instead of `IsolatedStorageFileStream`.

[[For Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)]

Comment: yes thank you it worked. Its now compiling but now its crashing. I replaced .txt file from web with a valid one. >> An exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Operation not permitted.

Comment: You need to switch the filenames, source is the first parameter. destination is the second. You also don't need to create the file first.

Comment: Try commenting out the file creation, you don't need it and it's actually opening the file so it can't be overwritten.